# yet-another-review-audit complaint

Tags: discussion, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20044203

What part of this post makes the question unsalvageable? It's a programming based question, isn't too broad...

For reference, here's the post:

> I've recently deployed my website infortion & It has started showing
>   in the google search results.
>
> But the problem is that when I see the results in google search by
>   typing site:infortion.com, then it's showing some unwanted pages in
>   results, like this one https://www.infortion.com/answer/260 (which
>   redirects the user to login first).
>
> In order to remove this page I added, `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">` about 2 weeks ago, but still it's showing
>   in the search results.
>
> How can we fix this problem?

Comment: This question used for the audit is already deleted. Review audits are automatic in nature .Require Editing isn't really appropriate anyways.

Comment: It was deleted as spam. It didn't look like spam to me.

Comment: @user2285236 The URL in the question 404s now. Perhaps it used to link to something like a blatant ad? Or perhaps this came across as an attempt to promote their own Q/A site by asking a question about it here? Or maybe this was a case of the spam getting edited out before the question got deleted.